# After group data in laravel how to show all rows from each group separately

Tags: laravel

I am using **groupBy** in laravel to make group, but after grouping I want to show all rows in separate array which are in the same group.

```
$menus = Order_menu_mapping::whereIn('order_id', $order_ids)
    ->groupBy('menu_id')
    ->get();
```

Here `$menus` just make group which keeps only one row. But I want to show all row inside of each group.

Comment: You need to share your related code. We can't just guess your code.

Comment: Did either of the below answers solve your issue? If so, **please may you mark it as accepted** so that the post can be shown as answered :)

Answer (score 4):

In your example you're adding `groupBy` to the query which is not the same as using `groupBy()` on a collection.

The `get()` method will perform the query and return a collection so you just need to put the `groupBy` after it:

```
$menus = Order_menu_mapping::whereIn('order_id', $order_ids)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('menu_id');
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Where did you get to know about it?

Comment: @Psycho Which bit?

Comment: that we could groupBy `after` the `get()`

Comment: @Psycho https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [mapToGroups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-maptogroups) . that groupBy works on the data set